# Accessing a USB device without using the drive letter in Windows

Tags: windows, usb

Is it possible to access a USB drive or Flash card without using the drive letter that Windows assigns it? I thought I read somewhere that the Volume GUID or something can be used but will that allow me to open it up in explorer once I identify it? The reason this is important to me is because there may not be enough drive letters to handle the number of drives so I want to be able to still access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MOUNTVOL by itself to get the drive ID.
[image]

Here you go:

```
MOUNTVOL C:\USB: \\?\Volume{ebc79032-5270-11d8-a724-806d6172696f}\ 

OR Winkey+R (Start-Run)  \\?\Volume{ebc79032-5270-11d8-a724-806d6172696f}\
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using NTFS, You can create 'volume mount points' in Windows. (Similar to *NIX, if you have used that).

Mount points make a folder on your filesystem (your C drive, say) point to another volume, so "C:\usb1" could actually contain the contents of a USB drive.

There are a couple of articles on the Microsoft site which should point you on your way:
[How to create and use mounted drives](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307889)
[About Volume Mount Points](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/prork/prdf_fls_ogex.mspx?mfr=true)